Microsoft Edge goes rogue: Dark Mode on iOS
Microsoft Edge's "Dark Mode" seems to go rogue on iOS. On Chrome/Safari/Firefox (iOS) & Chrome/Safari/Firefox/Edge (OSX/Windows) everything works as expected.
Ideally, I'd like Edge to not use dark mode at all. Next best would be to target Edge's Dark Mode on iOS specifically and add some CSS overwrites. Most interestingly, I'm having trouble with the latter as well as Edge on iOS somehow doesn't seem to listen to "prefers-color-scheme: dark" either.
Firstly, I've added this meta tag:
<meta name="color-scheme" content="only light">
Before I used this:
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
Secondly, I've added the following CSS (as per Chromium spec: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/auto-dark-theme):
:root {
    color-scheme: only light;
}

This works perfectly for listed environments, only Edge iOS doesn't work.
So, I tried to overwrite this by using the following to add a css target through JS.
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (
        window.matchMedia &&
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches &&
        /EdgiOS/.test(navigator.userAgent)
    ) {
        document.body.classList.add('ios-edge-dark');
    }
});

In combination with CSS like this:
.ios-edge-dark {
        .hero-type-2 {
            .feature-icon {
                filter: $main-filter-neg;
            }
        }
}

This is where the real "fun" starts: Edge iOS is properly targeted and the code is functional. Except in InCognito-mode: when a user has enabled this, the second condition (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) is true in Light Mode as well.
So I decided to test if Edge iOS would listen to a media query in CSS (yes, I know, this would make no sense whatsoever):
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    .ios-edge-dark {
        .hero-type-2 {
            .feature-icon {
                filter: $main-filter-neg;
            }
        }
    }
}

You guessed it. Nothing. Edge (iOS, InCognito) thinks it's dark. When it is. Ánd isn't.
At this point I'm out of ideas (and experiencing flashbacks to IE).
I did find a recent post that hints at others experiencing the same issues, but no real solution is listed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1644468/inconsistent-dark-mode-behavior-in-edge-on-ios
Hopefully you guys have a solution! At this point I'm eager to get this to work, even if it includes a dirty JS-based workaround like the one I already tried. Thank you in advance!
P.S.: I tried to outline the issue as detailed as possible, to hopefully help others in the future. If you're experiencing the same issue, feel free to share your attempts for a fix. I'm happy to add those as well.

Do you enable dark mode in Edge settings? I test with Edge iOS, prefers-color-scheme will detect the dark mode setting in Edge, not the iOS system.
You can find the setting in Edge: click the ☰ button on the right bottom in Edge, then click Dark Mode. Only when you choose System default, the value of prefers-color-scheme will be the same as system. Actually, for Edge iOS, prefers-color-scheme reflects the dark/light mode in Edge settings.

I test again and indeed the issue exists in iOS Edge InPrivate window. I prefer it's an issue of iOS Edge and you can provide feedback to Edge team in Settings > Help and feedback.
Edge doesn't force dark mode. When you manually choose "Dark Mode" in Edge, you can disable this option: Hamburger menu ☰ > Settings > Appearance > Dark theme for all web pages.

I've edited the post to reflect the real issue. As I was using the InCognito-mode to debug, I initially didn't notice the issue (i.e. window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches being true in Light mode as well) is limited to InCognito-mode.
Real issue of course is the fact that Edge iOS forces dark mode, even if it's not available. However, I understand the reasoning behind this from Edge's perspective and believe I should consider this a feature, not a bug.

Now I can reproduce it. Please check my edited answer and I suggest that you provide feedback about this issue.
